# Are there explanation on which zombies do what in Infectonator 3?

Tags: infectonator-3

For example, what does toxic zombies do?

The game is [Infectonator 3](https://steamcommunity.com/app/666570/discussions/0/2828702372994886406/).

I couldn't find a complete list of what each unique zombie does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this list online, there are also some tips for strategies following the linked post below:

- **Common Zombie** - the back bone of your army, should max out these guys inbetween crafting quests.
- **Brute Zombie** - slow and lumbering with a smash attack. Can't infect.
- **Chubby Zombie** - no real use, but easy to get points in crafting since they only need 2 common zombies.
- **Vampire Zombie** - self heal is nice but and a pre-requisite to get *Draculo*.
- **Triggered Zombie** - for some reason despite being similar to a Berserker Zombie they don't seem to perform as well. They are really good if they go *Hulk Smash* on the enemy. They'll zip around the battlefield.
- **Bomber Zombie** - nice zombie that takes down enemies with them when they die.
- **Berserker Zombie** - when these guys enrage they will zip around the map smashing everything. They are naturally tanky to boot!
- **Military Zombies** - an upgraded version of the *Berserker* that explodes upon death. These guys zip around the battlefield when they enrage.
- **Draculo** - a unique unlocked after getting 20 kills with Vampire zombies. He life steals back health, has decent attack and defense and 50% infection to start off. He can also leap at enemies by doing a cool bat swarm attack. They'll infect everyone around them and turn into a giant snowball of zombies that will overwhelm the enemy. Late game with mutagen DNA and max mutation chance things will get crazy.
- **Kim Jang On** - a unique zombie that is unlocked after getting 100 kills in Asia (hence our starting point). He has a really high infection chance and does good combo with Draculo. Have those two infect everything and snowball across all defenses. He is a bit squishy but will explode upon death like a bomber zombie. Generally keep him alive to keep infecting everything in sight.
- **Mummy** - unlocked after 100 kills in the Middle East. A pretty good zombie that gets a decent infection chance. Works well with *Draculo* and *Kim Jang On*. He also AoE slows everything around him so your zombies can swarm over the unfortunate souls that get caught in it.
- **Tayrong and Taemoon** - eggplant alien zombies that require *Projectile Vomit*, *Death Grip* and *Jump Scare DNA*.
- **Doomon** - unlocked after destroying a continent. Pretty good unique with a ranged explosive attack. Also comes with two imp zombies when he spawns.
- **Yeti** - a unique zombie that is unlocked after getting 100 kills in snow areas (ie: Russia and Canada). A really tanky unique that you should pop ontop the ZITs once your zombie infected snow ball collides with the enemy ZIT squad or boss. His AoE smash knocks enemies around and his takiness will let him soak up damage. He is meant to work with your group! He is one of two 'tank' unique zombies that are available.
- **Kruggy** - unlocked after infecting 250 people. Very useful early on for his movement speed buff due to your zombies being slow early game. Place him ontop of your horde. Since he *usually* casts his speed buff on the first enemy he sees, this will cause your horde to zip towards the ZITs and overwhelm them before they can fight back. Sometimes Kruggy doesn't cast his speed buff and the "Kruggy Bomb" ends up being a dud.

Source, [Gameplay tips](https://gameplay.tips/guides/2428-infectonator-3-apocalypse.html).